# How to compile C++ under Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: c++, gcc

I cut&pasted the below code from [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696225/null-pointer-to-object-problems) into a file called "avishay.cpp" and then ran

```
gcc avishay.cpp
```

only to get the following error messages from the linker. What went wrong, what should I have done?

```
carl@carl-ubuntu:~/Projects/StackOverflow$ gcc -static avishay.cpp 
/tmp/cccRNW34.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
avishay.cpp:(.text+0x41): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
avishay.cpp:(.text+0x46): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
/tmp/cccRNW34.o: In function `A::func()':
avishay.cpp:(.text._ZN1A4funcEv[A::func()]+0x11): undefined reference to `std::cout'
avishay.cpp:(.text._ZN1A4funcEv[A::func()]+0x16): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
avishay.cpp:(.text._ZN1A4funcEv[A::func()]+0x1e): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
avishay.cpp:(.text._ZN1A4funcEv[A::func()]+0x26): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&))'
avishay.cpp:(.text._ZN1A4funcEv[A::func()]+0x36): undefined reference to `std::cout'
avishay.cpp:(.text._ZN1A4funcEv[A::func()]+0x3b): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)'
/tmp/cccRNW34.o:(.eh_frame+0x12): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The C++ code (not my code, I was just trying to run it):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
private:
   int _dmember;

public:
   void func()
   {
     cout<<"Inside A!! "<<endl;
     cout<<_dmember; // crash when reach here.
   }
};

int main ()

{

    A* a= NULL;

    a->func(); // prints "Inside A!!!" 

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/203548/981959

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You should use `g++`, not `gcc`, to compile C++ programs.

For this particular program, I just typed

```
make avishay
```

and let `make` figure out the rest. Gives your executable a decent name, too, instead of `a.out`.

Comment: Another +1 (if I could) for the "make" tip. I never knew make could/would do that!

Comment: How does 'make' work here? I tried "make serial-rob.c" and it says "Nothing to be done for.."

Comment: The trick, I think, is to let it use its implicit rules. If it works for you like it did for me, then "make serial-rob" (without the .c) should do it.

Comment: the reason why `make serial-rob.c` doesn't work, is because that file is already made, it's there already.  on the other hand, when make looks for a file named serial-rob, it's not there, but it has an implicit rule for making *.c into *.o and that into just *

Answer (score 12):

You probably should use g++ rather than gcc.

Comment: Thanks. Just yesterday I didn't know how to spell "C++ programmer" and today I are one!

Answer (score 9):

Yes, use g++ to compile. It will automatically add all the references to libstdc++ which are necessary to link the program.

```
g++ source.cpp -o source
```

If you omit the `-o` parameter, the resultant executable will be named `a.out`. In any case, executable permissions have already been set, so no need to `chmod` anything.

Also, the code will give you undefined behaviour (and probably a SIGSEGV) as you are dereferencing a NULL pointer and trying to call a member function on an object that doesn't exist, so it most certainly will not print anything. It will probably crash or do some funky dance.

Comment: Yeah, the code was part of another question (linked) and got its due thrashing there. For just a quick test, I don't mind the program being called a.out, and I knew about -o. My main problem was with the compiler name, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Update your apt-get:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install g++
```

Run your program.cpp:

```
$ g++ program.cpp
$ ./a.out
```

Comment: Out of the other answers , this one is more clear and to the point . Thanks a lot .

Answer (score 4):

g++ is the C++ compiler under linux. The code looks right. It is possible that you are missing a library reference which is used as such:

g++ -l{library name here (math fns use "m")} codefile.cpp

Answer (score 4):

Use

> g++

space followed by the program name. 
e.g:

> `g++ prog.cpp`

if the filename was "prog.cpp" in this case.
if you want to run the program write:

```
./prog
```

so i used

> "prog"

because it was my filename.

Comment: The output file will be "a.out" unless you use the `-o` flag

Answer (score 4):

even you can compile your c++ code by gcc 
Sounds funny ?? Yes it is.
try it

```
$  gcc avishay.cpp -lstdc++
```

enjoy

Answer (score 2):

Use g++. And make sure you have the relevant libraries installed.

Comment: I paid good money for Ubuntu... oh wait, I didn't! But yeah, it turns out the problem was just in how I called the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

you can use g++ --std=c++0x example.cpp -o example

Answer (score 1):

To compile `source.cpp`, run

```
g++ source.cpp
```

This command will compile `source.cpp` to file `a.out` in the same directory.
To run the compiled file, run

```
./a.out
```

If you compile another source file, with `g++ source2.cpp`, the new compiled file `a.out` will overwrite the `a.out` generated with `source.cpp`

If you want to compile `source.cpp` to a specific file, say `compiledfile`,
run

```
g++ source.cpp -o compiledfile
```

*or*

```
g++ -o compiledfile source.cpp
```

This will create the `compiledfile` which is the compiled binary file. to run the `compiledfile`, run

```
./compiledfile
```

If `g++` is not in your `$PATH`, replace g++ with `/usr/bin/g++`.

Answer (score 0):

Install gcc and try the video below.
Try this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A6v2Ceqy4Tk
Hope it will works for you.