# undefined reference to std::ios_base::Init::Init()

Tags: c++, linker-errors

I'm working on learning OOP with C++ and having a problem. I'm sure its a memory allocation problem but cant seem to get my head around it. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

My Client Code

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include "Box.cpp"

    using namespace std;

    int main(){
        Box *box = new Box;
        return 0;
    }
```

My Box Class...

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    class Box{

        private:
            double width;
            double height;
            double perimeter;
            double area;


        public:
            Box(){
                cout << "Box created" << endl;
            }

            ~Box(){
                cout << "Box Destroyed" << endl;
            }

            double getWidth(){
                //
                return this->width;
            }

            double getHeight(){
                //
                return this->height;
            }

            double getArea(){
                //
                return this->area;
            }

            double getPerimeter(){
                //
                return this->perimeter;
            }

            void setWidth(double w){
                //
                this->width = w;
                if(!this->height){
                    computeSetArea(this->width, this->height);
                    computeSetPerimeter(this->width, this->height);
                }
            }

            void setHeight(double h){
                //
                this->height = h;
                if(!this->width){
                    computeSetArea(this->width, this->height);
                    computeSetPerimeter(this->width, this->height);
                }
            }

        private:
            void computeSetArea(double w, double h){
                //
                this->area = w*h;
            }

            void computeSetPerimeter(double w, double h){
                //
                this->perimeter = (w * 2) + (h + 2);
            }
    };
```

I use gcc and execute:

```
    gcc Box.cpp client.cpp -o mainfile
```

After such I receive this error.

```
/tmp/ccaVb21k.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
Box.cpp:(.text+0x1d): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
Box.cpp:(.text+0x22): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
/tmp/ccaVb21k.o:(.eh_frame+0x12): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
/tmp/ccjtbzi4.o: In function `main':
client.cpp:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned int)'
client.cpp:(.text+0x3f): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
/tmp/ccjtbzi4.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
client.cpp:(.text+0x6c): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
client.cpp:(.text+0x71): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
/tmp/ccjtbzi4.o: In function `Box::Box()':
client.cpp:(.text._ZN3BoxC1Ev[Box::Box()]+0x11): undefined reference to `std::cout'
client.cpp:(.text._ZN3BoxC1Ev[Box::Box()]+0x16): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
client.cpp:(.text._ZN3BoxC1Ev[Box::Box()]+0x1e): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
client.cpp:(.text._ZN3BoxC1Ev[Box::Box()]+0x26): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&))'
/tmp/ccjtbzi4.o:(.eh_frame+0x12): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
/tmp/ccjtbzi4.o:(.eh_frame+0x4b): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: please take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696300/how-to-compile-c-under-ubuntu-linux?rq=1

Comment: By convention .h files contain the class definition, while the .cpp files contain the class implementation, so you should either: split your definition out to a .h file, and keep the implementation in the cpp, or rename your .cpp to .h (since it's really a .h with the implementation inlined). If you *do* rename the file to .h, please remove the using namespace std; from the .h file, as that it is bad practice to pollute the global namespace inside a header file.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your code compiles fine, you're getting a linker error (`ld` is the linker, and it's returning 1 (error)), which is complaining about missing c++ libs.

To fix, you'll need to add the stdc++ lib to your commandline, or use g++.

Replace `gcc` with `g++` or add `-lstdc++` to your gcc command line.

`gcc Box.cpp client.cpp -o mainfile -lstdc++`

or

`g++ Box.cpp client.cpp -o mainfile`

This will link the std c++ library with your compiled code. Using `g++`, you can omit this step.

Answer (score 1):

Setting up your class structure like this works for me:

Box.h:

```
class Box
{
public:
    Box();
    ~Box();

    double getWidth();
    double getHeight();
    double getArea();
    double getPerimeter();
    void setWidth(double w);
    void setHeight(double h);
    void computeSetArea(double w, double h);
    void computeSetPerimeter(double w, double h);

private:
    double width;
    double height;
    double perimeter;
    double area;
};
```

And then for Box.cpp:

```
#include "box.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Box::Box(){
    cout << "Box created" << endl;
}

Box::~Box(){
    cout << "Box Destroyed" << endl;
}

double Box::getWidth(){
    return this->width;
}

double Box::getHeight(){
    return this->height;
}

double Box::getArea(){
    return this->area;
}

double Box::getPerimeter(){
    return this->perimeter;
}

void Box::setWidth(double w){
    this->width = w;
    if(!this->height){
        computeSetArea(this->width, this->height);
        computeSetPerimeter(this->width, this->height);
    }
}

void Box::setHeight(double h){
    this->height = h;
    if(!this->width){
        computeSetArea(this->width, this->height);
        computeSetPerimeter(this->width, this->height);
    }
}

void Box::computeSetArea(double w, double h){
    this->area = w*h;
}

void Box::computeSetPerimeter(double w, double h) {
    this->perimeter = (w * 2) + (h + 2);
}
```

Output:

```
Box created
```

Comment: Should i compile with the header file source file or just the header?

Comment: Just the source files, never directly compile headers. Also never include one source file in another (like your code above).

Comment: @seanr, Hi Sean, yes just like John says.  I used: "g++ Box.cpp main.cpp -o mainfile"   then to run of course I used: "./mainfile"  Did this work for you?

Comment: @john, Hi John, Box.h and Box.cpp are separate files, hope that clarifies what I listed. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much ill try to research more on why to use headers and why not include cpp files directly inside your source files.

Comment: @roybatty I wasn't refering to your code but to the code originally posted by seanr.

Comment: This works because you used g++, instead of g++, not because of how you've laid out your classes.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use g++ instead of gcc.