# OpenCV for Android: undefined reference to std::ios_base::Init::Init() while linking

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, opencv, android-ndk

I have seen the similar questions [undefined reference to std::ios_base::Init::Init()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20010244/undefined-reference-to-stdios-baseinitinit) and [undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906275/undefined-reference-to-stdios-baseinitinit) but I'm not sure whether I have the same situation.

I'm configuring `opencv for android 3.4.7` on `Android Studio 3.5`. I imported libs of opencv by editing `CMakeList.txt` and `build.gradle`:

```
set(opencv_version OpenCV3-android-sdk)

set(OpenCV_STATIC ON)
set(OpenCV_DIR /home/lynx/Android/Proj/${opencv_version}/sdk/native/jni)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
if (OpenCV_FOUND)
    message(WARNING "opencv libs: ${OpenCV_LIBS}")
else (OpenCV_FOUND)
    message(WARNING "opencv not found!")
endif(OpenCV_FOUND)

target_link_libraries(
        ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['/home/lynx/Android/Proj/OpenCV3-android-sdk/sdk/native/libs']
    }
}
```

and my `native-lib.cpp` is

```cpp
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_example_stitch_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject /* this */) {

    std::string hello = "Hello from OpenCV " + (std::string)CV_VERSION;

    return env->NewStringUTF(hello.c_str());
}
```

When building the project it shows many `undefined reference` errors from the file of `opencv`. It seems not the problem of linking `cpp` files with `c` linker: it called `clang++` to do the task and when not using opencv, the project can be build successful.

So is it because that I didn't correctly configured `opencv`?

Answer (score 0):

This is usually a case of using a library built against a different STL than you're using. I can't tell with the information you've given, but there are a lot of other questions on SO where people build their app with libc++ but build opencv with libstdc++. These are not compatible. See [NDK - problems after GNUSTL has been removed from the NDK (revision r18)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52410712/632035).